# How to truncate seconds from timestamp in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following field in my table:

```
VISIT_DATE TIMESTAMP(0)
```

And it is holding time like that:

```
2022-01-13 11:04:15
```

Could someone tell me is it possible to cut off that seconds? I really don't need them.
I want to hold time in the following format:

```
2022-01-13 11:04
```

Comment: You mean this? `SELECT date_trunc('minute',VISIT_DATE)`?

Comment: If this is only a formatting issue then  `SELECT to_char(VISIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either truncate the timestamp by minutes using `date_trunc`, which will return a timestamp without seconds, or use `to_char` if it is only about formatting the output:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute',VISIT_DATE) FROM t;
SELECT to_char(VISIT_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') FROM t;
```

Demo:

Using `date_trunc` (result as timestamp):

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute','2022-01-13 11:04:15'::timestamp);

     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2022-01-13 11:04:00
(1 Zeile)
```

Using `to_char` (result as text):

```
SELECT to_char('2022-01-13 11:04:15'::timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi');

     to_char      
------------------
 2022-01-13 11:04
```

Comment: It is working when someone want to retrieve data from database.
But I want simple timestamp field in my table without that seconds at all. Is it possible? Or it is just stupid question.

Comment: @Karord I see. Well, you cannot change the data type to not store seconds. What you can do is to se them to 0 in your insert/upates or just ignore them in query time as I demonstrated above. To really store these timestamps in the format you want you'd need to store them as text, which isn't a good idea :) cheers